# How can i make an Application crash to trigger wermgr.exe?

Tags: powershell, crash, crash-reports

I need to trigger the Windows Error Reporting service (in a natural way) to investigate something. Therefore I have to crash an application. Preferably I would like to do this via script, to automate and reconstruct this step easily.
Preferably i would like to crash an unimportant process like a self-created notepad.exe process or the powershell/cmd session the script is running in. Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: for several ideas on the subject, take a look at >>> c++ - Force crash an application - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284913/force-crash-an-application

Answer (score 1):

ok, i did it via this powershell script

```
$code = @"
using System;
namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(){
            Environment.FailFast("a");
        }
    }
}
"@
 
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp 
iex "[HelloWorld.Program]::Main()"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it can help future readers.

Comment: The code does only call `Environment.FailFast("a")`, for which documentation exists at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.failfast?view=net-6.0